Inserting an RTF string into a MigraDoc document
I would like to insert a string with RTF format, contained in a database, into a PDF document via MigraDoc (PDFsharp-MigraDoc-GDI 6.1.1).
I found a way to create RTF from MigraDoc, but I can't insert a ready-made text into a paragraph.
This is the code I use, how can I get a paragraph with the RTF text inside?
        Document document = new Document();
        Paragraph paragraph = document.LastSection.AddParagraph();
        string cText = File.ReadAllText("text.txt");//Here I would like to insert my RTF text            
        paragraph.AddText(cText);//
        //paragraph.AddFormattedText(File.ReadAllText("text.rtf")); //I Try this, but not work  
        PdfDocumentRenderer renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer();
        renderer.Document = document;
        renderer.RenderDocument();
        string filename = "HelloMigraDoc.pdf";
        renderer.PdfDocument.Save(filename);


Parse the RTF and convert the relevant parts to MigraDoc objects.

Unfortunately I don't know how to do it.
